# Access Text of Span Object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have ul's on my webpage similar to the one below and I'm trying to loop through each of them to grab a span within the li. Below is an example of how it appears in my HTML:

```
<ul id="item-NineAM" class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item w-100 border-dark past">
<span class="badge badge-dark" id="item-time">09:15 AM</span>
<p class="m-1 w-75 item-text">fsda</p>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="trashCan"><span class="oi oi-trash"></span></button></li>
</ul>
```

I've set up an interval to grab the span with id #item-time and pass it into my audit function

```
const listGroup = $(".card .list-group li #item-time");
    $.each(listGroup, function(i, itemSpan){
         console.log(itemSpan)
          auditItem(itemSpan)
    })
```

I've verified in the console that the span is passed into function but I cannot seem to grab the text of it.

```
<span class="badge badge-dark" id="item-time">09:15 AM</span>
```

I need to grab the time that's inside of the span. My console tells me it's an object. Any ideas? I've tried .text() and .innerHTML but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery selector you're assigning to `listGroup` should be pretty general, so you wouldn't include an id as you'd only get one match.

It looks like you're misusing `id`. Remember, you can only have a single instance of `id` and it should only be used to indicate uniqueness. Instead you want `item-time` to be a class since you can have several instances of classes.

I've corrected some others in your html as well.

```js
const listGroup = $(".list-group li span.item-time");
    $.each(listGroup, function(){
         console.log($(this).text())
          //auditItem(itemSpan)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group item-NineAM">
  <li class="list-group-item w-100 border-dark past">
    <span class="badge badge-dark item-time">09:15 AM</span>
    <p class="m-1 w-75 item-text">fsda</p>
    <button class="btn btn-danger trashCan">
      <span class="oi oi-trash"></span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gotcha. I've generalized the listGroup variable, updated my HTML so item-time is now a class and expanded my function to accept the text of the span along with the li itself to make my function work. Thank you!